# How to combine two loops into one in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have this part of code that is responsible for adding rule to Imperva for specific server.

There is a lof of nested variables so rather than explaining all parts of it I will just focus on a problem.

The issue is there can't be two loops inside of this task.

I added **loop: "{{ list_of_codes }}"** and there is also old part of code using with_items -> **with_items: "{{ ic_dc_stat_list.json | default({}) | json_query('DCs[?name==`Fontend_USA`].id') }}"**

This is the task I am talking about:

```
    - name: "Add [USA] Rule"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      uri:
        url: "{{ ic_api_url_sites_rules }}/add"
        method: POST
        validate_certs: false
        body: "{{ ic_auth }}&\
        site_id={{ _site_id }}&\
        dc_id={{ ic_dc_stat_id }}&\
        name=USA&\
        filter=CountryCode == {{ item }}&\
        {{ rules.action.frw_dc }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_codes }}"
      vars:
        ic_dc_stat_id: "{{ item }}"
        _site_id: "{{ ic_site_stat.json.site_id | default(incapsula_brand_domain.site_id) | default(site_id)}}"
      with_items: "{{ ic_dc_stat_list.json | default({}) | json_query('DCs[?name==`Fontend_USA`].id') }}"
      when: ( not ic_rules.json.delivery_rules | json_query('Forward[?name==`USA`]') )
            and ( ic_abigail and not ic_cs )
      register: ic_rules_latam_stat
      changed_when: "'skipped' not in ic_rules_latam_stat"
```

Loop **list_of_codes** should adding country codes here **filter=CountryCode == {{ item }}**.

This is details of mentioned loop:

```
list_of_codes:
 - "MX" # Mexico
 - "GT" # Guatemala
 - "HN" # Honduras
 - "NI" # Nicaragua
 - "CU" # Cuba
 - "DO" # Dominican Republic
 - "CR" # Costa Rica
 - "SV" # El Salvador
 - "PA" # Panama
```

I am looking for the best way to implement **list_of_codes**, but how to do this when there is already one loop in task -> **with_items: "{{ ic_dc_stat_list.json | default({}) | json_query('DCs[?name==`Fontend_USA`].id') }}"** which is used here: **ic_dc_stat_id: "{{ item }}"**

I though about jinja2, but now sure how to implement it here.

Please, help me to understand how to fix it.

Comment: See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Edit the question, reduce the complexity, and minimize the code. Add the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

To focus on the problem, let's assume we have the lists below

```yaml
list_of_codes:
  - MX
  - GT

list_of_ids:
  - 1A
  - 1B
```

If the [cartesian product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/nested.html#nested-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists) is needed the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list_of_codes:
      - MX
      - GT
    list_of_ids:
      - 1A
      - 1B
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ list_of_codes }}"
        - "{{ list_of_ids }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml | grep msg:
  msg: MX - 1A
  msg: MX - 1B
  msg: GT - 1A
  msg: GT - 1B
```